# Fixed position offset top and bottom

Tags: javascript, css, offset, fixed, sidebar

I have a site I am working on, that is just about there, but not quite: http://joshrodg.com/new/blog/

I'm working on the sidebar (red section), the sidebar is the only section with content, just the standard WordPress blogroll, but what I noticed is that at the very top of the page it overflows into the header (yellow section).

Right now that sidebar has an absolute position, but the content in the sidebar has a fixed position so that when you navigate the blog you always see the search bar, links, etc. in the same position.

I have some javascript that prevents the fixed-positioned content from overflowing into the footer, but how do I prevent it from overflowing into the header as well...I'm not sure how to tweak the javascript I'm already using to make this work.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hh4s6nye/
Live Example: http://joshrodg.com/new/blog/

The code:

```
<div id="head">
    <h4>This is the header</h4>
    <p>This is the header</p>
</div>

<div id="blog">
    <section>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h4>Your title here</h4>
            <p>Your content here</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h4>Your title here</h4>
            <p>Your content here</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div id="side">
        <div class="fixed">
            <h4>Your title here</h4>
            <p>Your content here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="foot">
    <h4>This is the footer</h4>
    <p>This is the footer</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
      background: #ff00ff;
}

.wrap {
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 1000px;
}

/* Head */
#head {
      background: #ffff00;
      height: 500px;
}

/* Blog */
#blog {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
}

 section {
      color: #fff;
}

 section:nth-child(even) {
      background: #000;
}

 section:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #0000ff;
}

 section .wrap {
      min-height: 500px;
}

/* Side */
#side {
      background: #ff0000;
      color: #fff;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 300px;
}

#side .fixed {
      bottom: 10px;
      position: fixed;
}

/* Foot */
#foot {
      background: #00ff00;
      height: 500px;
}
```

The JS:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
           function checkOffset() {
                if($('#side .fixed').offset().top + $('#side .fixed').height() >= $('#foot').offset().top - 10) $('#side .fixed').css('position', 'absolute');
                if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#foot').offset().top) $('#side .fixed').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
    }
      $(document).scroll(function() {
           checkOffset();
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hh4s6nye/
Live Example: http://joshrodg.com/new/blog/

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...so, after some continued searching I was able to find: https://github.com/senff/Sticky-Anything. This is also available as a WordPress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-menu-or-anything-on-scroll/

This is a jQuery plugin that allows you to make anything sticky.

So, basically, I removed the existing JS I was using and added `jq-sticky-anything.min.js` to my JS folder. Then I customized the options:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#side .fixed').stickThis({
            pushup: '#foot'
        });
    });
</script>
```

There are more options, but for me, all I'm using this for is to stop my sticky element at the footer.

The HTML did not change, the css had a minor change and that was to the `fixed` class:

```
.fixed {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

So, essentially the jQuery is now controlling the fixed div.

This is a great solution because it does exactly what I want. The sidebar scrolls, but the content is never cutoff or covered in any way.

Live example: http://joshrodg.com/new/blog/
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/75fdsqhr/5/

Hope this helps someone!

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

you can add z-index to #blog.

```
/* Blog */
#blog {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Working Link :-

https://jsfiddle.net/hh4s6nye/1/

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your suggestion, I added the z-index but that cuts off the search box and some of the other links towards the top of the content: http://joshrodg.com/new/blog/. Is there a way to tweak the JS to prevent the fixed content div from scrolling up past a certain point so all the content remains visible?